# Need help using par3dinterp and playwidget to rotate plot using rgl in R

Tags: r, rgl

I am working through the relatively new document - User Interaction in WebGL (March 8, 2017) at
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/vignettes/WebGL.html

About 2/3 of way down the page is the following code example which performs a "complex" rotation animation of the plot:

`M <- r3dDefaults$userMatrix
fn <- par3dinterp(time = (0:2)*0.75, userMatrix = list(M,
                                      rotate3d(M, pi/2, 1, 0, 0),
                                      rotate3d(M, pi/2, 0, 1, 0)) )
rglwidget() %>%
playwidget(par3dinterpControl(fn, 0, 3, steps=15),
       step = 0.01, loop = TRUE, rate = 0.5)`

I want to do something much simpler - rotate the plot around the z-axis at a constant rate but my noggin seems to be missing something fundamental about time specification and values function is evaluated at.... I can get it to rotate part of the way round 360degress then swing back but not keep going round... Please help.

Thanks in advance
Alex

[I am trying permutations on something like the following....

`M <- r3dDefaults$userMatrix
fn <- par3dinterp(time = 0:3, userMatrix = list(M,
                                      rotate3d(M, pi/2, 0, 0, 1),
                                      rotate3d(M, pi, 0, 0, 1), M) )
rglwidget() %>%
playwidget(par3dinterpControl(fn, 0, 2, steps=15),
       step = 0.01, loop = TRUE)`
 ]

Answer (score 1):

For simple spinning, use `spin3d()` rather than `par3dinterp()`.  (You should be able to use the latter, but as you've seen, it's hard to get it right; in fact, I think there's a bug in the way it interpolates.)

For example, to spin at 5 rpm (the `spin3d()` default), a full rotation takes 12 seconds.  You'd want something like this:

```
fn <- spin3d()
rglwidget() %>%
playwidget(par3dinterpControl(fn, 0, 12, steps = 40),
           step = 0.01)
```

The choice of 40 steps is kind of arbitrary, but you don't want that number too small, because you'll get distortions of the scene as it interpolates between those steps.  On the other hand, the amount of data it puts in the web page is proportional to the value, so you don't want it unnecessarily big.

Comment: Works great, very much appreciated. My basic error was assuming spin3d did not work with widgets and you had to use par3dinterp to control any movement you wished. I am also somewhat reassured that coding par3ddinterp and par3dintercontrol is not totally elementary.